# Forcing insert in Postgresql when INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgreql table (first table):

```
CREATE TABLE public.getxo_todoseniales_hv
(
  id numeric(8,0),
  "GEOMETRY" geometry,
  "Comentario" character varying,
  "Codigo" character varying,
  "Leyenda" character varying,
  "FechaImpla" date,
  "FechaCambi" date,
  "FechaRetir" date,
  rotacion numeric,
  variacion numeric(10,0),
  fecha_mecanizacion timestamp without time zone,
  usuario_mecanizacion character varying,
  tipo_variacion character varying,
  variacion_posterior numeric(10,0),
  CONSTRAINT getxo_todoseniales_hv_id_key UNIQUE (id, variacion)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
```

And I have another table (second table):

```
CREATE TABLE public.getxo_todoseniales_borrar
(
  id numeric(8,0),
  "GEOMETRY" geometry,
  "Comentario" character varying,
  "Codigo" character varying,
  "Leyenda" character varying,
  "FechaImpla" date,
  "FechaCambi" date,
  "FechaRetir" date,
  rotacion numeric,
  CONSTRAINT getxo_todoseniales_hv_id_key UNIQUE (id, variacion)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
```

Ok, notice that the second table has the same fields except from the last 5 fields.

Now I want to insert all the rows from first table to second table but without having to specify the columns one by one. I will have to execute this query in a PL/SQL function and I it will be used for a lot of tables which fields won't be known to me. The only constant is that first table will have the same columns except from the last five colums (on the second table that I don't need them).

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO getxo_todoseniales_borrar (SELECT * FROM getxo_todoseniales_hv);
```

But as expected, I am gettin the error:

```
Insert has more expressions than target columns
```

Is there any way to force postgresql to insert the data which is in the columns they have in common?

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: why not just list em?.. `INSERT INTO getxo_todoseniales_borrar SELECT id , "GEOMETRY" ,
  "Comentario" ,
  "Codigo" ,
  "Leyenda",
  "FechaImpla" ,
  "FechaCambi",
  "FechaRetir" ,
  rotacion FROM getxo_todoseniales_hv;`

Comment: Either provide the target columns for the insert statement or only select those columns that are needed. Ideally both. Neither `select *` nor an insert without a column list is considered good programming style

Comment: I don't know the columns I just know that the first columns in both tables are the same except from last 5 columns which I don't need them...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the column name using this syntax

```
select string_agg(column_name,',') from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table_name' limit ((select count(*) from table_name)-5) ;
```

now you find the column name in , separated value.
After that you run the syntax.

```
insert into table_name select column_name from table_name
```

Comment: Although not a complete solution to the question, I think this is a useful start. The missing steps are a) limiting the column list to remove the last 5 columns; and b) turning this into a dynamic SQL query in pl/pgsql.

Comment: added the syntax limit ((select count(*) from table_name)-5)